Como hacer que sql distinga 1 de 10 en un contenga '~'?
Busco sentencia que me seleccione todos los números que contengan el campo SECTORS.
En QGIS (SQL): "SECTORS" ~  @atlas_featureid
Pero por ejemplo si tengo en SECTORS: 2,3,10. Me marca el 2,3,10 pero también el 1... Es decir no me distingue 1 de 10.
